# Listen to multiple events on the same element to fire

Tags: jquery, listener, jquery-events, jquery-deferred

I need your help, because I'm at the end of my wits. I am trying to wait for multiple events on form elements. To show you what I mean, here is an example:

```
var el = this,
    conditions = $( this ).data( 'conditions' ),
    promises = [];

$( conditions ).each( function () {
    var def = new $.Deferred(),
        condition = this;

    $( el ).hide();

    $( this.listener ).on( 'change', function () {
        if ( $( '#' + condition.target ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
            def.resolve( 'show' );
        } else {
            def.resolve( 'hide' );
        }

        promises.push( def );
    } );
} );

$.when.apply( undefined, promises ).done( function ( res ) {
    console.log( res );
} );
```

The idea behind this is, that I can listen to a select element and check the value that the user has selected. If the condition validates to true, another element is shown.

The problem now is: If I have another condition on the same element both listeners geht executed, one validating true, and the other false.

So I tried it with deferred. The above example works correctly for the first time. If the user is emitting an event again the deferred does not get resolved a second time. I was expecting this, because a promise can only resolve once.

The other way is, if I only use pure jQuery listeners, they both get fired and the last attached listener shows or hides the element. But i need to evaluate all listeners at once.

My question is now, how could I solve the problem? May someone give me a hint on how this could be implemented?

Comment: The usual way to code this is not to "wait for a specific sequence of multiple events".  As you have found, that is particularly hard to code.  But, rather you monitor whatever events are appropriate and then on each event, you check the current state of the other elements in the condition and see if all elements now meet your condition.  That type of code does not lend itself to promises.

Comment: For example, if you want to know when four checkboxes are all checked, you don't try to keep track of when all four click events have happened.  Instead, you put a click or change handler on each checkbox and when any checkbox state is changed, you examine that state of all four checkboxes at that moment and see if they are all four checked.  If so, you carry out your event.  If not, you do nothing.

Comment: Ok, that was in my mind too. I will try this. Thanks

Comment: ok, I think I got it now, will answer this with an example ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jfriend00 for giving me a hint on this.

Here is an example of what I ended up with:

```
var el = $( '#formfield-3' ),
    conditions = $( el ).data( 'conditions' ),
    targetConditions = {};

$( el ).on( 'condition.check', function () {
    var show = false;

    $.each( targetConditions, function ( key, target ) {
        switch ( key ) {
            case 'show':
                $.each( target, function ( key, value ) {
                    if ( ! show ) {
                        show = value.indexOf( true ) !== - 1;
                    }
                } );

                break;
        }
    } );

    if ( show ) {
        $( el ).parent( '.forminput-group' ).show();
    } else {
        $( el ).parent( '.forminput-group' ).hide();
    }
} );

$( conditions ).each( function () {
    var condition = this;

    if ( ! targetConditions[this.type] ) {
        targetConditions[this.type] = {};
    }

    if ( ! targetConditions[this.type][this.target] ) {
        targetConditions[this.type][this.target] = [];
    }

    if ( ! targetConditions[this.type][this.target][this.id] ) {
        targetConditions[this.type][this.target][this.id] = false;
    }

    $( el ).hide();

    $( this.listener ).on( 'change', function () {
        targetConditions[condition.type][condition.target][condition.id] = false;

        switch ( condition.condition ) {
            case 'selected':
                if ( $( '#' + condition.target ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                    targetConditions[condition.type][condition.target][condition.id] = true;
                }

                break;
        }

        $( el ).trigger( 'condition.check' );
    } );
} );
```

Here is a working form element tag that I used to test this:

```
<input id="formfield-1" name="sample" type="radio" value="1">
<input id="formfield-2" name="sample" type="radio" value="2">

<select id="formfield-3" data-conditions="[{"id":1,"target":"formfield-1","listener":"input[name=sample]:radio","type":"show","condition":"selected","value":null,"element":"select"},{"id":2,"target":"formfield-2","listener":"input[name=sample]:radio","type":"show","condition":"selected","value":null,"element":"select"}]">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option>Sample Value</option>
</select>
```

This would create two listeners on the radio group and whatever is selected the select box will be shown.

This is only a very small demonstration, but I hope if someone else has such a problem, I can help with this :)

Thanks a lot